# columnEdit not applying to my range of columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Script works really well but I have 12 columns and this script only works on A and B.

```
function onEditTwoWay(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName("Dep1");
  var sheet2 = sheet.getSheetByName("Dep2");

  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var value = cell.getValue();
  var currentRow = cell.getRow();
  var currentColumn = cell.getColumn();

  var activeWorksheet = ["Dep1","Dep2"];
  var columnEdit = [1,2,12];

   if(activeWorksheet.indexOf(ss.getActiveSheet().getName()) > -1 && 
  columnEdit.indexOf(currentColumn) >  -1  && currentRow > 1) {
  sheet1.getRange(currentRow, currentColumn).setValue(value);
  sheet2.getRange(currentRow, currentColumn).setValue(value);
    };
 };
```

Comment: Your onEdit will only work if the active cell is in column 1, 2 or 12.  Are you saying it doesn't work if the active cell is in column 12?  It this truely is an onEdit trigger all the cell information is in the event object `e`.

Comment: Wow @TheWizEd I feel silly. I thought I was working with the range and 12 was the last column in it. I added all other columns individually and it works fine. Ill post the answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var shts = ["Dep1", "Dep2"];
  var cols = [1, 2, 12];
  if (~shts.indexOf(sh.getName()) && ~cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    shts.forEach(name => {
      e.source.getSheetByName(name).getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).setValue(e.value);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All columns need to be entered in `columnEdit` so changed from
`columnEdit = [1,2,12]` to `columnEdit = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]`